# setCookie: CSRF no set by Angular4 sent by CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, cookies

I'm trying to get CSRF protection to working with *angular 4.2.4* on the frontend and *CodeIgniter 3.1.4* on the backend .

After solving CORS related bugs, I now can make requests to my REST-API without any error. But in the end the set-cookie header gets ignored: csrf-token and ci_session arent set as cookie => all checks fail.

A basic overview of important and related settings:
Backend: config.php(CSRF)

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'XSRF-TOKEN';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

Backend: rest.php(CORS)

```
$config['check_cors'] = TRUE;
$config['allow_any_cors_domain'] = FALSE;
$config['allowed_cors_origins'] = ['http://localhost:4200/'];
```

Frontend: rest_service.php

```
login(data: object){
   return this.http.patch(this.loginUrl, data,{withCredentials:true}).map(this.extractData)
};
ping() {
   return this.http.get(this.pingUrl, {withCredentials:true, responseType: 'text'});//.map(this.extractData);
}
```

In my research, I read - that without including withCredentials:true the csrf token would not be set as cookie.

To fix a CORS Problem, I created a proxy.conf.json file looking like this:

```
{
  "/ping": {
    "target": "https://xxx.xxx/live/index.php/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  },
  "/users/*": {
    "target": "https://xxx.xxx/live/index.php/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

So I feel like I've tried every single suggestion out there.
And the XSRF-TOKEN still doesn't get set.

I'm looking forward to any suggestions. Thank you